# SQL: select from table where it doesnt exist in other for a user

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `Test` and `StudentTest` with these structures:

`Test`:

```
testID     subject     totalPoints     schoolSubject
1          Programming 100             informatics
2          Webdesign   80              informatics
...
```

`StudentTest`:

```
studentTestID     userID     testID     timeStudied     points     date
1                 1          1          60              60         2015-05-20
2                 2          1          100             80         2015-05-20
2                 2          2          95             75         2015-05-20
...
```

Now I want to make a page where the user can fill in his marks (in `StudentTest`), but I only want to show the tests where the user doesn't already have marks for. For example if user 1 is logged in he should only see test 2 because user 1 has no marks for that test. User 2 shouldn't see anything because he has marks for all the existing tests.

I don't know what the SQL should look like.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Looks like a homework question?

Comment: Have a look at outer join

Comment: You need to do some research and give it a go yourself before asking people to help you out hear on SO. If you've already tried something then add it to your question so people can give you a helping hand.

Comment: I've already tried this, it's just an example for user 1:                       SELECT Test.testID, Test.subject, Test.schoolSubject, Test.totalPoints 
FROM Test 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * 
 FROM StudentTest 
 WHERE StudentTest.testID = Test.testID AND 
 StudentTest.userID = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT subject, schoolSubject
FROM   Test t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   StudentTest st
                   WHERE  t.testId = st.testId
                   -- And possibly limit it to a single studentId
                  )
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. Just one typo in your code: EXIST schould be EXISTS.

Comment: @GillisWerrebrouck arg, stupid typos... Fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

Use the left join null filter pattern:

```
SELECT subject, schoolSubject
FROM Test t
LEFT JOIN StudentTest st ON t.testId = st.testId
WHERE st.testId IS NULL
```